# How to compress multiple files in linux using python script?

Tags: regex, linux, python-3.x, compression

I want to compress all logs which matches the pattern entered by the user for which i am using the below code but getting an error.

```
import subprocess
input=input("Enter log details to compress")
subprocess.call(['gzip',input],shell=True)
```

Input given as : purato.log.2017-08*

Error : gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving `gzip` the string `purato.log.2017-08*` in python, however in when you execute `gzip purato.log.2017-08*` in the shell, the wild card `*` substituted before `gzip` is invoked.

In order to replicate this behavior, enable `shell` on the `call()` function.

```
subprocess.call(['gzip purato.log.2017-08*'],shell=True)
```

Comment: i'm getting this error

gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression

Comment: It needs to be all one string for the shell to interpret it: `['gzip %s' % input]`.